# Electron.NETでモーダルウィンドウを作る方法

Tags: electron, asp.net-core

Electron.NETでモーダルウィンドウを表示する方法が分かりません。
以下のコードを試しました。

```
var parentWindow = ElectronNET.API.Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First();
        
var options = new BrowserWindowOptions()
    {
        Modal = true,
    };
var childWindow = await ElectronNET.API.Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(options);
childWindow.SetParentWindow(parentWindow);

bool isModal = await childWindow.IsModalAsync(); // => false
```

SetParentWindowで子画面に設定することはできますが、モーダレスウィンドウで表示されます。
モーダルオプションのコメントに子画面であることが条件と記載されているので、子画面としてウィンドウを作成する方法があるのだと思うのですが見つけられませんでした。

[Electron.NET/ElectronNET.API/Entities/BrowserWindowOptions.cs /](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/blob/master/ElectronNET.API/Entities/BrowserWindowOptions.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// Whether this is a modal window. This only works when the window is a child
/// window.Default is false.
/// </summary>
public bool Modal { get; set; }
```

モーダルウィンドウを表示する方法をご存知でしたら教えてください。

Comment: この辺の記事が`electron.net modal window`とか`electron.net modal dialog window`の検索で見つかるので参考になるかも。[electron.net-api-demos/ElectronNET-API-Demos/Views/Windows/Index.cshtml](https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos/blob/master/ElectronNET-API-Demos/Views/Windows/Index.cshtml), [Electron.NET/ElectronNET.API/Dialog.cs](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/blob/master/ElectronNET.API/Dialog.cs), [How to create a child modal window in Electron.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55792274/9014308)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記サイトを確認しましたが、求める情報はありませんでした。もう少し調べて無理そうなら別のアプローチを模索してみようと思います。